# Efficient Way to Find Partial Duplicates in Dataset

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a large dataset (~20,000 rows) consisting of persons and their info, and am looking for a way to identify potential duplicate persons within this dataset. These duplicates are not necessarily perfect matches since they have been entered manually and some contain typos.

ex)

```
   LastName MiddleName FirstName DOB
1  Farmer    Berry      Dave     1/1/2004
2  Place       D.       Tom      8/4/2001
3  Famrer      B.       Dave     01/01/2004
4  Ander      Kate      Linda    12/26/1954
5  Place jr.  David     Tom      8/4/2001
    ...
```

In this case row 1 and 3, and rows 2 and 5 would need to be flagged as duplicates. The only solution I have been able to come up with is O(n^2), and consists of iterating through the entire dataset for each record in the dataset, comparing fields for partial matches and flagging rows if matching criteria is met.

Is there a more elegant solution for this?

Edit For clarity: it is possible that none of the fields contain an exact match. People are manually entering all of these individuals very quickly, so there is a lot of opportunity for typos/ incorrect information

```
      LastName MiddleName FirstName DOB
1   John-adams    T.        Samuel  1/15/2021 
2   Jhon-adams   Tom        Sam     10/15/2021
```

These 2 rows should be flagged as potential duplicates.

Comment: What is the criterion for a partial match? At least one field being the same in two different rows?

Comment: `O(n)` solution would be: walk through your data once and perform data cleansing: ie. enforce that a DOB like `1/1/2004` appears as `01/01/2004`. Convert all middle names to middle initial, remove jr. from last names, etc.... This cleansing helps you here and it will probably help with your other purposes down the road. Then you can walk through and find exact matches (possibly allowing for NaN's to be disregarded when comparing).

Comment: Another `O(n)` option is to create a `set()` for each column. Then, iterating over each row, check if the value in each column already exists in its respective column set (this is an `O(1)` operation). If it exists, you can print or store the row number as a possible duplicate row. If it does not exist, insert the value in the column set (this is also an `O(1)` operation).

Comment: @CharlesDupont Sorry I think I was a little unclear in my question. Technically its possible for none of the fields to be exact matches, which is what has been causing me the trouble. My current solution consists is: for each row, compare to every other row, determine partial string match for FName, LName, DOB. If  at least 2 of FName & LName & DOB match > 80%, we add corresponding rows to output dataset for manual inspection.

Comment: I think this kind of work is relevant... http://iir.ruc.edu.cn/~luwei/publications/Efficiently%20Supporting%20Edit%20Distance%20based%20String%20Similarity%20Search.pdf